# Joomla 3 Global Configuration missing header

Tags: php, css, joomla, styles, administrator

I don't update joomla recently.
I don't install any new 3rd party extension like component, module or ...
I've checked all "administrator/components/com_config" and "administrator/libraries" for finding any file injection (hack) and find NO new malware files has been copied there recently.

All pages on Administrator are good as before.
Just com_config page is missed now any header codes even any css styles are missing.

the source code of "administrator/index.php?option=com_config" starts with this lines:

```
<form action="/administrator/index.php?option=com_config" id="application-form" method="post" name="adminForm" class="form-validate">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar" class="span2">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">System</li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="index.php?option=com_config">Global Configuration</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Component</li>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the problem by overwriting via ftp all joomla files.
This is the right version for you:
https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-7-2/Joomla_3-7.2-Stable-Update_Package.zip?format=zip

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I did update to this version. everything was ok but this update can't correct my problem. Everything is like before. Plus my Menu Pages on administrator got a blank page. So i roll back to my backup.

Comment: What is you actual version of joomla? Your php and mysql server version are ok for joomla 3? If you have blank page there was and error and probably was write in log file of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstall the Joomla core:
Joomla Update > Live Update > Reinstall Joomla core files.

Comment: If it has compromised files so much I would not trust to a live update

Comment: It updates only the corefiles not the overrides. But you are right. Best way test it on an test server with a backup

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did update my joomla core. but this this can't correct my problem. Everything is like before. Plus my Menu Pages on administrator got a blank page. So i roll back to my backup.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a third party plugin (System - JV Libraries) who overloaded JHtmlJquery class in the core of Joomla.

I could realized adding this code to: **"administrator/templates/isis/index.php"**

```
<?php
  $reflector = new ReflectionClass('JHtmlJquery');
  echo $reflector->getFileName();
?>
```

and get this: **var/www/html/cuweb/plugins/system/jvlibs/javascripts/jvjslib.php**

So I opened that file and erased HJtmlJquery class (below)

```
abstract class JHtmlJquery
{
    /**
     * @var    array  Array containing information for loaded files
     * @since  3.0
     */
    protected static $loaded = array();

    /**
     * Method to load the jQuery JavaScript framework into the document head
     *
     * If debugging mode is on an uncompressed version of jQuery is included for easier debugging.
     *
     * @param   boolean  $noConflict  True to load jQuery in noConflict mode [optional]
     * @param   mixed    $debug       Is debugging mode on? [optional]
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.0
     */
    public static function framework($noConflict = true, $debug = null)
    {
        JVJSLib::add('jquery');
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Method to load the jQuery UI JavaScript framework into the document head
     *
     * If debugging mode is on an uncompressed version of jQuery UI is included for easier debugging.
     *
     * @param   array  $components  The jQuery UI components to load [optional]
     * @param   mixed  $debug       Is debugging mode on? [optional]
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.0
     */
    public static function ui(array $components = array('core'), $debug = null)
    {                                                                                       
        JVJSLib::add('jquery.ui.interactions');
        return;
    }
}
```